# Django/Selenium how to prevent fixtures from being created more than once (during LiveServerTestCase run)?

Tags: django, testing, selenium, django-testing

Problem: I'm using factory_boy to create some mock up objects so I don't have to use fixtures in my tests (this isn't causing the problem though). I have a function called _create_fixtures() that is called in the setUp() of my class which is causing the following IntegrityErrors: http://dpaste.org/ggC5U/.

I would like to create these objects only on the first run of the tests so that they don't keep getting these errors.

For more information, this is the test classes: http://dpaste.org/a6eFb/

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please put your code examples in your question text, not linked to a third-party site.